# numerical values of the column of a matrix getting modified when converting into data.frame

Tags: r

Running on R 2.13, I want to have a data.frame of several column, the first one being of numeric type, the others of character type. When I am creating my object, the values of the first column are getting transformed in a way that I don't expect or understand. Please see the code below.

> tmp <- cbind(1:10,rep("aa",10))
>
> tmp

```
  [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "aa"
[2,] "2"  "aa"
[3,] "3"  "aa"
[4,] "4"  "aa"
[5,] "5"  "aa"
[6,] "6"  "aa"
[7,] "7"  "aa"
[8,] "8"  "aa"
[9,] "9"  "aa"
[10,] "10" "aa"
```

> tmp <- data.frame(tmp)
>
> tmp

```
   X1 X2
1   1 aa
2   2 aa
3   3 aa
4   4 aa
5   5 aa
6   6 aa
7   7 aa
8   8 aa
9   9 aa
10 10 aa
```

> tmp[,1] <- as.numeric(tmp[,1])
>
> tmp

```
   X1 X2
1   1 aa
2   3 aa
3   4 aa
4   5 aa
5   6 aa
6   7 aa
7   8 aa
8   9 aa
9  10 aa
10  2 aa
```

For some reason, the values of the first column are getting changed. I must be doing something obviously wrong here, can someone point me a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> tmp <- data.frame(cbind(1:10,rep("aa",10)))
> str(tmp)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X1: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","10","2","3",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2
 $ X2: Factor w/ 1 level "aa": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

As you can see above, `tmp$X1` got converted into a factor, which is what's causing the behaviour you're seeing.

Try:

```
tmp[,1] <- as.numeric(as.character(tmp[,1]))
```

Answer (score 5):

@aix's answer is a correct diagnosis.  However, probably what you want to do is to create a data frame directly:

```
data.frame(1:10,rep("aa",10))
```

Rather than `cbind`ing first (which makes a matrix) and then converting to a data frame.

You might want to give your variables sensible names rather than the weird ones they will end up with via the `data.frame` command above (`X1.10` and `rep..aa...10.`):

```
data.frame(var1=1:10,var2=rep("aa",10))
```

Since `data.frame` replicates its arguments, you can shorten this even a bit more:

```
data.frame(var1=1:10,var2="aa")
```

And if you really want a character vector rather than a factor for the second column, you can use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or wrap `var2` in `I()` (i.e. `var2=I("aa")`)

Comment: in the example I gave you are right, but the thing I actually want to do is to transform a bigger matrix. My first column is a function of several columns of my original inputs, then the other columns are functions of the original inputs as well (stuff that I keep, stuff that I originally modify). So I will go with as.numeric(as.character(xx)) instead of using data.frame directly.

Comment: I still suspect there's a way to do it directly with `data.frame()`, but it's up to you.